# How to use count specific element and get count value on target xml from source xml using xslt?

Tags: xslt, count, mapping

I wanna read the element count and apply the target xml element from a specific source element.

1. this is source xml to be read and counting POSEX field

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <INVOIC01>
    <IDOC>
            <POSEX>000010</POSEX>
            <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
            <MENEE>EA</MENEE>
            <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
            <BRGEW>13.000</BRGEW>
            <PSTYV>TAN</PSTYV>
            <WERKS>3000</WERKS>
   </IDOC>
    <IDOC>
            <POSEX>000010</POSEX>
            <MENGE>1.000</MENGE>
            <MENEE>EA</MENEE>
            <GEWEI>KGM</GEWEI>
            <BRGEW>13.000</BRGEW>
            <PSTYV>TAN</PSTYV>
            <WERKS>3000</WERKS>
   </IDOC>
   </INVOIC01>
   ```
2. my xslt code

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
       <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
       <xsl:template match="/">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
       </xsl:template>
       <!-- ============================================================================================= -->
       <!-- Template: Enter the ordinal number in POSEX-->
       <!-- ============================================================================================= -->
       <xsl:template match="POSEX">
           <D_6066>
               <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::POSEX)+1"/>
           </D_6066>
       </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
3. outcome xml after run xslt code

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

            <D_6066>1</D_6066>
            1.000
            EA
            KGM
            13.000
            TAN
            3000


            <D_6066>2</D_6066>
            1.000
            EA
            KGM
            13.000
            TAN
            3000
   ```

I want to expect target xml as below after run xslt.

```
<D_6066>2</D_6066>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want your output document to consist of a single `D_6066` element containing the count of the number of `POSEX` elements in the input document.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <D_6066>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//POSEX)"/>
        </D_6066>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: my targe xml element was gone and only available field D_6066 with posex count . would you be able to produce target xml logic as well?       <S_CNT>
         <C_C270>
            <D_6069>2</D_6069>
            <D_6066/>
         </C_C270>
      </S_CNT>